# Updated conditional probability - Elo rating

Tags: probability

Consider a tournament where all teams play against each other, and suppose we have the probability for win-draw-loss for every match (e.g. with the prediction from Elo rating).

Is there a feasible way write out/calculate the probability that each team wins the tournament? Note that the result of one match affects the probabilities of further matches.

Maybe some backwards recursivity, since the problem is easier when there are less matches left to play?